# Mysql multiple delete or rows in one statement. Is there a limit?

Tags: mysql, delete-row

I'm using a statement like this with PHP/Mysql:

```
DELETE FROM `site1` . `users` WHERE `email` IN ('eric@me.net', 'joe@aol.com', 'bill@me.com')
```

I may have a few hundred or a thounsand at a time, will this be a problem for MySql to handle?
Is there a limit to the array used for the "IN" function?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in), there is no specific limit on the number of arguments to `IN`:

"The number of values in the IN list is only limited by the max_allowed_packet value."

Answer (score 2):

Best practice I would batch it by no more than 100 and if they must be deleted at once you could wrap them in a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a temporary table containing the values, and refer to that from the query.